# Erros de transporte de sistema em php para outro computador

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, easyphp

Tenho um sistema que funciona perfeitamente no computador(A) que foi desenvolvido e, ao passar pro computador(B) servidor com as mesmas configurações, a mesma versão do EasyPHP(5.2.10) e etc, apresentou muitos, mas muitos erros.

Depois de instalados nesse computador(B) o easyPHP(5.2.10) e o phpMyAdmin, eu simplesmente exportei o SQL do banco do sistema web que estava no computador(A), copiei a pasta, passei pro computador(B) e importei o SQL nele.

Era pro sistema web funcionar perfeitamente do mesmo jeito que funciona no computador(A), mas quando ele é rodado no computador(B) aparecem erros em todas as páginas, inclusive de cadastro e apresentação de registros.

Alguém sabe se existe um jeito de eu resolver esse problema ou se vou ter que ir em erro por erro adivinhar o problema e resolver?

Comment: Você tem o arquivo .conf do apache dos dois computadores ?

Comment: Precisa saber se as versões do php são a mesma e quais erros sãos...

Comment: de computador local para site de hospedagem?

Comment: São dois computadores físicos com a mesma versão do easyPHP instalada, a 5.2.10